# passing an input text value to another and modify width of an image

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have an image with (vue) as id and created two input type text,one with the id (hauteur) and the other with (largeur).
i try to catch the value written in the (hauteur) text and pass it to my image (vue) and then take the height of this image and pass it to the  (largeur) input text.
i created a div as a button (valider) and added an event .click .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#valider").click(function(){

    var largeur=$('input[name=largeur]').val();

    $('#vue').css('width','largeur');
    var hauteur=$("#vue").css('height');
    $('input[name=hauteur]').val('hauteur');
  });
});
```

but i just have hauteur(as string not the number) as value in my input.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing hauteur as a string literal not as a variable. Remove the quotes.

In the line

```
$('input[name=hauteur]').val('hauteur');
```

change 'hauteur' to hauteur

```
$('input[name=hauteur]').val(hauteur);
```

Secondly change

```
$('#vue').css('width','largeur');
```

to

```
$('#vue').css('width', largeur);
```

As for the assignment to that variable. You shouldn't use `.css('height')`. You should use `.height()`.

If you use `.css()`, you are retrieving the value of the style that you have applied. Not the actual height of the rendered image in your browser.

Also, if you have the id largeur applied to your input, you don't need to use the name to select the input, simply select it as you have `#vue`:

```
$('#largeur')
```

The same stands for hauteur.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're passing `'largeur'` and `'hauteur'` as strings, not as variables.  Remove the quote marks.

```
$('#vue').css('width', largeur);
// ...
$('input[name=hauteur]').val(hauteur);
```

Comment: Yeah it works ,thank you, but in my second text it shows a value with (px) at the end how can i just show the number without px?

Comment: `$('input[name=hauteur]').val(parseInt(hauteur));`

Comment: See James McDonnell's answer (re: using `.height()` instead of `.css('height')`. Actually, see his answer in general, it's the better version of mine.